# Show my last selection

Tags: jquery, select

I have a large section of select tags, where I use jQuery to show the user an overview of his selections. This works perfectly, except for the fact that my code doesn't only show my last selection. So if i change my selection, the previous selections remain in the overview and my new selection gets listed below.

[See the image for my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8flLa.png)

Here I've changed my selection several times, and they all get listed. I only want to show my most recent selection (For each select tag)

Here is my script;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SORTERING select').change(function() {
        label = $(this).closest("p").prev().find('label').html();
        content = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#OutputTXT').append('<p><b>' +label+ ': </b>' +content+ '</p>');
    });
});
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem? Thanks for any help!

Here's the HTML for the `select` tag, as requested:

```
<div id="SORTERING">
    <p class="chck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc"/>
        <label for="c4"><span></span>Avtale</label>
    </p>
    <p class="select">
        <select id="s4" name="s4">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="salgge">DB Salg GE</option>
            <option value="salgkin">DB Salg KIN</option>
            <option value="salghk">DB Salg HK</option>
            <option value="nei">DB Nei</option>
            <option value="samf">DB Samfakturering</option>
            <option value="eksge">DB Kunder GE</option>
            <option value="ekshk">DB Kunder HK</option>
            <option value="ekskin">DB Kunder KIN</option>
            <option value="del">Slett</option>
            <option value="forward">Viderefør</option>
            <option value="liste1">HK Nordland</option>
            <option value="liste2">Kveldsliste</option>
            <option value="addlist">Legg til liste</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `append()` (as this will create a new element on each selection) use `html()` as this will over-write the value each time:

```
$('#OutputTXT').html('<p><b>' + label + ':</b> ' + content + '</p>');
```

> i want it to show one line for each selection instead of replacing it

In this case the logic becomes more complex as you need to check if a `p` exists for the chosen select and if so update it, otherwise create it. Something like this:

```
$('#SORTERING select').change(function() {
    label = $(this).closest("p").prev().find('label').html();
    content = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var $p = $('#output_' + this.id);
    if (!$p.length)
        $p = $('<p id="output_' + this.id + '"></p>').appendTo('#OutputTXT');

    $p.html('<b>' + label + ': </b>' + content);
});
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. It still adds another line instead of replacing it.

Comment: However, it replaces too much. (If i make a selection under "Avtaler" it changes, but if I make a selection on "Tilbakeringing" this also replaces my selection from "avtaler"..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: With .append () it shows my selection from each select tag. (Which i have several of) But with .html () allthough it replaces if i change the original select tag, it also replaces it if I change a different select tag. Which I want listet beneath)

Comment: So you want to see only one `p` tag per `select`?

Comment: Yes! As of now, it replaces the p tag i choose for each selection i make. But i want it to show one line for each selection instead of replacing it. But replacing if I change the one i've already selected. If you understand me?

Comment: Just to try and explain in a better way (I'm sorry, English is not my first language, so there may be some language barrier..)

I have selection tags and Check boxes goien from ID c/s1 - 20. So there are 20 different ones to choose from.

If I now change the selection on s4 it replaces itself, but if I change s5 now, it replaces s4.

With the last code you gave me, nothing happend when I made a selection..

Comment: It would help a lot if you could setup a full example of your code in http://jsfiddle.net. At the moment I'm just guessing what your code looks like from the single `select` that you've shown

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=KQhMaFvw6r

For some reason it doesnt work at all in jsfiddle...